# Gradient flow of dirichlet energy: meaning

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, gradient-flows

The Dirichlet energy $E\colon L^2(\mathbb{R}^n) \to \mathbb{R}  $ is defined by (for $u \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$)
$$
E(u)= \frac{1}{2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} ||\nabla u(x)||^2 dx
$$
It is a classical fact that the heat equation
$$
\partial_t u = \Delta u
$$
can be regarded as the gradient flow of the Dirichlet energy in $L^2$.
However I cannot understand

1. How to derive this, at least formally (in the sense that I admit manipulations which are not really rigorous)
2. What this means rigorously (as I do not know how to compute the gradient of $E$).

Any help?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1409167/gradient-flow-of-dirichlet-energy?rq=1). It's indeed a duplicate, but I am not sure if you are satisfied with the answer there.

Comment: Do you know how to compute the [first variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_variation) using the [functional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) ? If so, you can use it [as demonstrated here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations#Dirichlet's_principle).